# File I/O in iOS?

Tags: ios

What is the recommended way to write/read data from files in iOS? All I see is:

1. Bulk I/O. E.g, contentsAtPath of NSFileManager or writeToFile of NSString. These are memory intensive and impractical for complex data structure.
2. Very low level buffer based I/O from NSFileHandle.

What seems to be missing is API that sits somewhere in between that can read int, float and strings (like Java's readUTF/writeUTF). The fscanf of C is a good example. I can roll my own. But, I was wondering if Foundation framework already has something that I have missed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Bibhas, the low-level C API's (including fscanf) are available. For granular IO many apps utilize an RDBMS (SQLite) or NSUserDefaults. This may or may not meet your needs.

iOS also supports memory mapped files.
http://shift.net.nz/2011/04/memory-mapped-files-on-ios-worth-checking-out/

Answer (score 0):

> What seems to be missing is API that sits somewhere in between that can read int, float and strings (like Java's readUTF/writeUTF). The fscanf of C is a good example.

There's nothing wrong with using C's File I/O facilities if that suits your needs more appropriately than the higher level interfaces in Foundation.

(as your follow up comment shows you have discovered)